# Firebase query `TypeError` using `firestore.FieldPath.documentId()`

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore data structure looks like this:

[image]

`db.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', '20210106.0'` does not work, but I am not sure why. I need to read it as a `float`, so I can use `=>` or `=<` as Start Date and End Date in my query.

In the console I get this error message: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'FieldPath' of undefined'`

Here is my code:

```
actions: {
    getFireBaseOrders(state){
        db.collection(`ordersOptimized`).where(
            db.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(),
            '==',
            '20210106.0').onSnapshot((res) => {
                const changes = res.docChanges();
                changes.forEach((change) => {
                    if (change.type === "added") {
                        let payload = change.doc.data();
                        state.commit("firebaseOrders", payload);
                    }
                });
            });
    },
```

What am I missing? How do I make the condition work?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to listen to changes occuring to the Firestore **document** with ID `20210106.0`, just do as follows:

```
db.collection("ordersOptimized").doc("20210106.0").get()
   .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        // ....
        // Based on your database screenshot you should loop over the 
        // JavaScript object returned by doc.data()
        // Something like

        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(doc.data())) {
            console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        }

        // See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries
    });
```

Since `20210106.0` is the ID of a document in the `ordersOptimized`collection, only one document with this ID can exist in this collection. Therefore you should not use a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) (i.e. `db.collection('...').where('...')`) in order to listen to changes to this document.

---

On this other hand, if you want to listen to ALL the documents of the `ordersOptimized` collection, see the corresponding [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#listen_to_multiple_documents_in_a_collection).

Comment: @AnjoBautistaLiwanag Hi, did you have the opportunity to look at the proposed approach?